# how do i enable php fileinfo extension

Tags: php, fileinfo

I'm trying to install a script and it gives me this error: *"Fileinfo PHP Extension Is Required
This PHP extension is required. You'll need to enable it or ask your hosting provider to do it for you to continue the installation"*

Anyone know how i can do this from cpanel? Would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: did you check phpinfo()? I mean it's supposed to be enabled by default as of PHP 5.3.0. http://php.net/manual/en/fileinfo.installation.php
Maybe time for your host to upgrade the system :/ also : "However, versions prior to 5.3+ may use the » discontinued PECL extension."

Comment: Which version of PHP do you use?

Answer (score 0):

PHP extensions are generally not possible to enable from CPanel or similar software. You would actually need to contact your hosting provider to do that, as it requires editing of system files (`php.ini`, for one, but since this is a PECL extension they would actually need to install it for you in the first place). However, don't get your hopes up -- shared hosting providers will generally not accomodate such requests, especially if you happen to be using free hosting. You can try, but it's very likely they'll just tell you they won't do it.